# Google PageSpeed recommends to use small inline CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pagespeed

I try to optimize my webpage so it loads very quickly. My question is this:

Google PageSpeed recommends to use small inline CSS so there are less round-trip times.

I have one compressed CSS file included via

`<link href="/path/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

with 12 kb.

Would it be more smart to include it like this:

`<style>........</style>`

even though it is cached by the browser when I use `<link>`? I mean 12 kb is not really much and I've seen Google inlining much larger stylesheets directly into the HTML.

Same question for two .js files with about 500 kb both.

Here is a screenshot with firebug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6h71.png

What do you think?

Comment: It means small selectors like `#someID { color: #000; }` are put in the `<style>` tag. If you have selectors with lots of styling, leave them in the minified css file.

Comment: Go to https://www.google.de/ and look at the first <style> tag in the <head>. I wouldn't say Google is dumb when it comes to speed so I still wonder why they inline these large stylesheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css is all right, but don't do it for the JS since the JS would parse itself. If you can, put the JS link files onto the end of page (if it is not 100% essential)

Comment: So I can inline the CSS directly or should I leave it as it is now with <link>? Javascript is just before the </body> tag already

Comment: Well you have to try and see. No one will tell you if it works better. But I would definitely try the inline.

Comment: I just noticed that my stylesheet does not have 2.9 kb but 12 kb! Would you let the browser cache it with <link> in this case?

Comment: Does this css stylesheet is used multiple times on differents pages? If so I would left it as <link>, if it is a single page app use inline